# ERROR 000539: Error running expression:rcexec ()

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator, error-000539

I have got this error when tried to make slope less than 20 degree through Raster Calculator. One day before I installed Python 2.7.13 and after, this error appeared. When I delete the downloaded python, ArcGIS is not opening at all. Could it be the reason for the program not working properly?

[image]

Comment: Please always include errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS Desktop installs its own copy of Python, usually in `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3`.  If you have installed your own download of Python it probably installed directly into `C:\Python27` and any Python paths in the Windows settings may have been updated into this location.

This will stop arcpy from working.  To get arcpy to work again you can do a repair install of ArcGIS Desktop which will fix the paths for arcpy.

This happened to me the other day, a repair didn't take long and everything worked normally again afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you advice how I can do a repair install? Is there any website for this?

Comment: @Ruslan Run the ArcGIS Desktop installer.  Since you already have ArcGIS Desktop installed, you'll get 3 options - Modify, Repair, and Uninstall.  Choose Repair.

Comment: @Ruslan you may also be able to run the installer from Control Panel > Add Remove Programs (or similar) and see if there's a Change option on the ArcGIS Desktop item in the list of installed apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed any Python  version please clean it and repair the ArcGIS